# What is the purpose of capacitive coupling of qubits?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-electrodynamics, quantum-entanglement, interactions

I am new to quantum computing , so my question may seem pretty vague.
I was looking for how qubits(superconducting charge qubits) are coupled together and came across capacitive coupling, can you tell me why do we need a capacitor for this, why cannot we do this using simple connections(using wires etc)?

Comment: Do you know basic circuits? The answer to your question really has almost nothing to do with quantum mechanics, much less quantum computing, we need to know what you already know about basic circuit design etc.

Comment: I know the basic capacitor, but I don't know much about basic circuits , just very basic concepts

Comment: Hmm, in that case there are a few steps to answering your question: 1) Understand that a single nonlinear resonant circuit can be used as a qubit, 2) Understand what happens when you connect two resonant circuits through a wire or through a capacitor (those cases are *very* different), 3) Combine those two ideas to understand how connecting two superconducting qubits through a capacitor produces a system that can be used as two interacting qubits.

Comment: Actually I just thought of something: Is it obvious to you that if you connect two resonant circuits with a wire that you wind up with a single resonance? On the other hand, if you connect two resonance circuits through a (small) capacitor, you  have two resonances?

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/581070/